# Using machine learning to make predictions for unlabelled, incomplete inputs with deep relationships

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

I want to use machine learning to predict which cities a person has been to.

There many relationships / correlations in this data;

e.g. visiting SFO means you're more likely to have visited geographically close cities like LAX;

e.g. visiting RUH and LHR means you're more likely to have visited SYD, because RUH is a common layover stop for SYD <-> LHR, and people tend to travel between SYD and LHR a lot (just an example)

etc. The point is that there are many levels of deep relationships in this data.

However, the dataset I have is:

- unlabelled: i.e. I know 'John: CITY_124:Yes, CITY_48:Yes, CITY_482:no; Dave: CITY_124:No, CITY_58:No; etc"; so I have no additional inputs like proximity of cities
- incomplete: I know that John has definitely visited CITY_124 and CITY_48, and has not visited CITY_482, but John **may or may not** have visited CITY_1, CITY_2, CITY_3, etc.

Fortunately, I can **ask** a person if he has been to a city, and I will get a correct answer. However, asking incurs a heavy cost/penalty, so I can't ask for every city, and hence I have to also figure out which cities will give me the most value / information.

My goal is to have a function that can give me a probability of [Arbitrary person] having visited an [Arbitrary city].

What machine learning techniques would be appropriate for this problem?